# An efficient algorithm to generate a set of tuples satisfying a given upper bound for a distance between two arbitrary elements

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, algorithms, discrete-optimization

Let $T_i^n$ denote a particular tuple of $n$ natural numbers (here $i < n!$ and we assume that the tuple contains all elements of the set $\{0, 1, \ldots, n-2, n-1\}$, i.e. there are no duplicates). For example, $$\begin{array}{l}
T_0^4 = (0,1,2,3),\\
T_1^4 = (0,1,3,2),\\
 \ldots \\
T_{23}^4 = (3,2,1,0).
\end{array}$$

Assuming that $(x, y)$ are two different elements of a given tuple $T$, let $d(T, x, y)$ denote the number of elements between $x$ and $y$ in $T$. For example, if $T = (3, 0, 1, 4, 2)$, we have $$d(T, 3, 0) = d(T, 1, 0) = d(T, 2, 4) = d(T, 4, 2) = 0, d(T, 3, 2) = 3.$$

Question: given an arbitrary natural number $n > 2$ and a natural number $k$ such that $0 \leq k \le n - 3$, is there an efficient algorithm to generate a set $$S = \{T_{j_0}^n, T_{j_1}^n, \ldots, T_{j_m}^n\}$$ of tuples such that for any pair $(x, y)$ of elements of the set $\{0, 1, \ldots, n-2, n-1\}$ there exists an element $T_{j_z}^n$ of $S$ such that $d(T_{j_z}^n, x, y) \leq k$, yet the cardinality of $S$ is *as small as possible*?

The algorithm is expected to operate as follows: start with $T_0^n$; permute $T_0^n$ to obtain $T_{j_0}^n$; permute $T_{j_0}^n$ to obtain $T_{j_1}^n$, etc. (to avoid storing a large number of tuples in memory).

Comment: Unless I don't understand the question, a simple counting argument shows that at least $n/4$ tuples are needed for $k=0$. (For fixed $k$ it is always a linear function of $n$). I think you should therefore specify a more achievable upper bound.

Comment: @Steven, I think you need at least $n/2$ tuples in the case where $k=0$ although everything else you said is correct. For any fixed $k$ the number of sets you'll need in $S$ is always linear in $n$.

Answer (score 1):

I will solve the case $k=0$ because it is in some sense also a solution to all other $k>0$.
Since in each tuple only $n-1$ pairs of elements are adjacent, you need at least $\frac{n(n-1)/2}{n-1} = \frac{n}{2}$ tuples.

There is a nice and simple divide-and-conquer algorithm that can solve the question for $k=0$ close to optimally, in some sense. The idea is: divide the numbers in two sets. Solve the problem for both sets (recursively), that is: make a collection of partial tuples in which all numbers are adjacent in some tuple. Then we only need to guarantee the adjacencies *between* the two sets.  This can be solved by interleaving and rotating the sets relative to each other.

For example, if the sets are $\{0,1,2,3\}$ and $\{4,5,6,7\}$, we could interleave them as $(4,0,5,1,6,2,7,3)$ and then rotate that to $(7,0,4,1,5,2,6,3)$ and so on. If the tuples were considered cyclical, than $n/2$ rotations (of step size 4) would suffice. For linear tuples, I could not find a better solution than doing $n/2-1$ rotations. In total $n-2$ tuples will be generated.

---

Implementing this recursively would be the most clean option, but since you explicitly asked for a function which takes a list and transforms it, I wrote a demo in Python of how the algorithm could look like.  Notice that (implemented like this) it only works for $n=2^k$; but all $n$ should be doable with some minor modifications to the algorithm.

```
def rotate(L, groupsize):
    n = len(L)
    M = list(L)
    for k in range(n//groupsize//2):
        for i in range(groupsize):
            M[k*2*groupsize + 2*i] = L[k*2*groupsize + (2*i +2)%(2*groupsize)]
    return M

def combine(L, groupsize):
    n = len(L)
    M = n*[0]
    for k in range(n//groupsize//2):
        for i in range(groupsize):
            M[k*groupsize*2 + 2*i + 1] = L[i+k*groupsize*2]
            M[k*groupsize*2 + 2*i]   = L[i+k*groupsize*2+groupsize]
    return M

def generateTuples(n):
    L = list(range(n))
    yield L
    groupsize = 2
    while groupsize < n:
        L = combine(L, groupsize)
        yield L
        for _ in range(groupsize-1 if groupsize>2 else 0):
            L = rotate(L, groupsize)
            yield L
        groupsize *= 2
```

Comment: “I will solve the case $k=0$ because it is in some sense also a solution to all other $k>0$.” — doesn’t this solution become more and more suboptimal as $k$ grows? If, say, $n=235$ and $k=12$, how many tuples will this algorithm generate?

Comment: True, but for any fixed $k$ it is only a constant factor worse than the optimal solution. However, I had the feeling that the algorithm could be tuned a little for larger $k$. Namely: if $k$ is larger, you can rotate fewer and further. (For cyclical tuples, this would again work out very nicely; but for lineair tuples you would have to be more careful about the numbers at the edges.)